# how to select the first entry in jira using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, jira

I'm new to python. I want to select the first entry of my query list in Jira using python selenium.

```
import selenium

chrome_path = "C:\Python37-32\chromedriver.exe"
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://jira.xxxx.com/issues/?filter=24005')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-options"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form-username"]').send_keys('xxxx')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form-password"]').send_keys('xxxx')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form-submit"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="content"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[3]').text
```

need to select every entry in the query list.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're able I would recommend using the Jira API for something like this (are you using cloud)? https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation.html

You would use your filter https://domain.atlassian.net/issues/?filter=24005 and you would have gotten all issues in this API request.

Example:

```
from jira import JIRA
issue_list = jira.search_issues("filter=24005")
for issue in issue_list:
    DO SOMETHING
```